# trigger mouse over event using jquery for css hover

Tags: css, triggers, mouseover

Am trying to trigger the mouse over event for this below links event on document . ready
but its not triggering the event.

http://codepen.io/zacharyolson/details/vzeyc#forks

Trying to do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.macbook').trigger('mouseover');

});
```

is there any way to trigger the over event. on document ready

Answer (score 1):

You cannot trigger the same event mouseover at once on two elements

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.macbook').trigger('mouseover');
$('.macbook-screen').trigger('mouseover');
});
```

So you need to consider on which element should be triggered just add trigger only to one element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.macbook-screen').trigger('mouseover');
});
```

Comment: same effect .. not triggering :(